# PHP, mysql, primary key remains unchanged for two records

Tags: php, mysql, insert-id

I've got following code, as seen, I have two INSERT statements, which insert two records -  one with current date and the second one -1 day. The problem seems to be with a mysql_insert_id. I'm getting following error:

> Duplicate entry '28' for key 'PRIMARY'

Looks like the ID remains the same for both statements and also the first "INSERT" is added without any trouble, the problem is at the line where trying to add the second record into the same table. Here's the script:

```
<?
include("session.php");
include("database_common.php");
if (isset($campaignName) & isset($campaignRedirect))    {
    $dataTable = 'qrData_'.$_SESSION['displayName'];
    $statTable = 'qrStat_'.$_SESSION['displayName'];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$dataTable." VALUES(".mysql_insert_id($connection).", '".$campaignRedirect."', '".$campaignName."');", $connection);
    $statBlank1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$statTable." VALUES(".mysql_insert_id($connection).", CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0, '".$campaignName."');", $connection);
    $statBlank2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$statTable." VALUES(".mysql_insert_id($connection).", CURDATE(), 0, '".$campaignName."');", $connection);
    if ($statBlank1) echo "stat 1 ok";
    else echo mysql_error($connection);
    if ($statBlank2) echo "stat 1 ok";
    else echo mysql_error($connection);
    if ($query) die("<center>Kampaň úspešne vytvorená<br><br><button      onclick='parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();' name='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Zatvoriť</button></center>");
    else die("<center>Vyskytla sa chyba. Prosím, zopakujte Vašu požiadavku.</center>"); 
}
?>
```

Here's a table structure:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,  `usageCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
`campaign` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: Firstly, `mysqli_report` is for `mysqli_` and not for `mysql_` functions.

Comment: whats the primary key of `qrStat_#` - does it include `campaignName` ?

Comment: remove parameter from mysql_insert_id..i.e. only mysql_insert_id is to be written..

Comment: @amdixon - "id" is the AI PK INT NOT NULL.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Yep, you're right. my mistake, but I've already removed it.

Comment: Already removed *what*? All we can see is the code with the mixed API's. Because of that we cannot provide an answer.

Comment: what about `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html or `INSERT ... SELECT` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: For the moment, I have to use mysql_* functions.

Comment: Can you post the schema of your tables, I'm fairly certain your `$statBlank1` & `$statBlank2` are conflicting with each other.

Comment: `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,  `usageCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  `campaign` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I made it a bit amish, but it works. I'm getting last id directly from mysql and increase it by 1 in a next record like this:

```
$statBlank1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$statTable." VALUES(ID, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0, '".$campaignName."');");
$statBlank2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$statTable." VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1, CURDATE(), 0, '".$campaignName."');", $connection);
```

ID in the first query is undefined, however table structure always changes NULL value to NOT NULL, which will be, in this case the next incremented value. Hope somebody will find this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

remove parameter from `mysqli_insert_id`..i.e. only `mysqli_insert_id` is to be written.. & echo the query to be inserted..you will get the value what is being inserted..use mysqli_free_result after each insert query

Comment: Look at the comments under the question - this is not the problem.

Comment: yes but the id remains unchanged due to above activity..if mysql_insert_id only will be used new value will be generated for each inserted query.

Comment: There are more problems than that. The OP is mixing API's which will not work.

Comment: Tried, result remain the same. First record is added second one gets duplicate id.

Comment: *"okay..use mysqli_free_result after each insert query"* - OP is using `mysql_`.

Comment: He should, but he is not.